Any useful bases for the topology induced by the $t$-Wasserstein distance?
I am working on $\mathbb R ^d$ equipped with the usual Euclidean metric. I know of one  nice base for $\mathcal W _t$, namely: $$\left\{ B_p (r) : r>0, p=\sum_{i=1} ^n \alpha_i \delta_{x_i},\text{ for some }n\in\mathbb N, x_i  \in \mathbb Q ^d, \alpha_i \in \mathbb Q, \alpha_i \text{ summing up to one} \right\}$$
i.e. open balls centered around Dirac masses on rational points with rational coefficients. Can one get a more explicit base? Any other bases you know of?
Many thanks in advance!

Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63567/basis-for-topology-of-weak-convergence-of-probability-measures.

Very useful indeed! Thanks!
